# Property 'X' does not exist on type 'number' - React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm mapping over brands, and while it's not loading, I'm displaying each brand properties, and while it's loading, I'm mapping over numbered/indexed array,
and displaying skeleton.

In JavaScript it's working fine, but TypeScript thinks it will map over the numbered array and display the brand properties, thus displaying the error:
'Property 'X' does not exist on type 'number',
when it tries to access brand.icon, brand.name, and brand?.sites.

```
{(loading ? Array.from(Array(6).keys()) : brands).map((brand, i, arr) => (
        <Fragment key={i}>
          <Accordion
            TransitionProps={{
              mountOnEnter: true,
              unmountOnExit: true,
            }}
            className={classes.expPanel}
            expanded={expanded === `panel${i + 1}`}
            onChange={handleChange(`panel${i + 1}`)}
          >
            <AccordionSummary
              className={classes.expPanelSummary}
              expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}
              aria-controls="panel1d-content"
              id="panel1d-header"
            >
              <ListItemIcon className={classes.brandIcon}>
                {loading ? renderSkeleton(28, 28, 'circle') : <Icon>{brand.icon}</Icon>}
              </ListItemIcon>
              {loading ? renderSkeleton() : <Typography>{brand.name}</Typography>}
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails className={classes.expPanelDetails}>
              <Sites sites={brand?.sites} readOnly={readOnly} />
            </AccordionDetails>
          </Accordion>
          {i < arr.length - 1 && <Divider />}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
```

Comment: Instead of checking `loading`, you could check `typeof brand === "number"`

Comment: Works, thanks.
Add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check if `brand` is a number it will narrow its type:

```
{typeof brand === "number" ? renderSkeleton(28, 28, 'circle') : <Icon>{brand.icon}</Icon>}
//                                                                     ^ now it's not a number
```